# QGIS tool or plugin for very quickly changing attribute values interactively

Tags: qgis

I am asking this here because it is hard to articulate this question into Google.

I am looking for a tool or plugin in QGIS which would allow me to digitize features (or change already digitized features) to have a certain set of pre-defined attributes. Perhaps something like a list of feature types in a sidebar, and when you select some features on the map canvas, then click on the feature type's name, it changes those feature to that feature type by assigning the attribute values associated with it.

Or even something like selecting features on the map, and then pressing a number key to automatically change it.

Does something like this exist already in QGIS or as a plugin? Because I was thinking of trying to make it myself if it does not.

After the discussion the comments I think what I am looking for is an equivalent to the ["Feature Templates"](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/about-feature-templates.htm) feature in ArcGIS desktop

Comment: Could you describe the intended workflow a bit more detailled? Because you can pre-define attributes, e.g. based on a classification or a range, and also change them later on for existing, selected features.

Comment: The quick attribution plugin could help a bit but does not implement the full set of requirements listed here. https://github.com/opengisch/quick_attribution/

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn Yes that looks like it is in the right direction, but I am imagining something in which you could save a sort of "template" feature with 1 or more attributes already specified, and by selecting the feature and then selecting the template from the list, the feature would fill out those attributes according to the template. I think I used something like this in ArcMap many years ago but the memory is fuzzy.

Comment: Attribute painter might be even better https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/attributePainter/